# Debug Installed App

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

How can I debug an app that was built with debugging turned on but is already installed on a phone?

I have tried to find a way to attach Android Studio to an existing app, but can't figure that out. Do I need to use adb in some way to do this? Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click in the fourth button in the bar (This is screenshot is from AndroidStudio 2.2, the icons have changed but the position is the same).

[image]

After that, it will prompt to you all running application that can have debug attached, just select it and you are now debugging.

[image]

Comment: Worked, but couldn't get debugging into C/C++ library code. Only showed Java. I had hoped this would work for C++, but still good to know. Ty

Comment: This would require setting `jniDebuggable true` (`debuggable` only counts for Java).